# Android Webview Autofill Information like address, passwords, personal information

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, chromium

I want to create Autofill functionality for my Android demo app same as Chromium does. I have information like address, personal information, passwords. How can I integrate all this stuff on my custom browser? Please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps,

1. Collect each keywords(words) which user tries to search.
2. Store in database with priorities

   - Number of time particular keyword is searched.
   - How much time user has spent on particular search.
   - Base on user likes.
   - If your database on cloud, you can also return what other user likes most.
   - Build searching patterns to identify priorities.
3. Try to return data based on priorities when user types a word.

Comment: I am not talking like this kind of Autofill. But I stored address fields, password fields in my database. Wherever  webpage find address field, it can be able to fetch data from database. Same as Google Chrome Autofill functionality.

Comment: Then store address and password, and when you find similar address, give a suggestion to user. If user selects, auto fill both of them. Simple!